# I want to access information from another script but I get this error " Int does not contain a definition for TakeDamage" Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

**This is the entire error**
'int' does not contain a definition for 'TakeDamage' and no accessible extension method 'TakeDamage' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Here is the scrip from where I should take the information**

**I wrote a text where I receive the error**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerStatus : MonoBehaviour
{
//health

    public int health;
    public int maxHealth = 10;
    
    //Damage
    
    int dmg = 4;
    //XP
    
    public int xp;
    public int LevelUp = 10;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        health = maxHealth;
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    public void TakeDamage(int amount)
    {
        health -= amount;
        if(health <=0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

}
```

**Here is the script that should receive the information**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnmStatus : MonoBehaviour
{
public PlayerStatus playerHealth;
public int damage = 2;

    //health
    public int health;
    public int maxHeath = 10;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    
    void Start()
    {
        health = maxHeath;   
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

*//Down here I receive the error*

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
    
            health.TakeDamage(damage);

//     if(health \>= 1)
//     {
//         playerHealth.TakeDamage(damage);
//     }
}

    void TakeDamage(int amount)
    {
        health -= amount;
        if (health <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

}
```

It is suppose to decrease ENM health when I click on him, afterwards I want to decrease player health if ENM is still alive (Health >= 1)

Answer (score 0):

You call health.TakeDamage(damage);
Because '.' is the way the calling public member in object or class. So error message is very correct. (health is int variable (public int health).
There is no TakeDamage() method in int class.)

Please change like under code.

```
private void OnMouseDown()
{
   TakeDamage(damage);    // health will decrease as much as damage amount
   
   // check playerHealth null and health(but who's health? enm or player?)
   // if u check player's health change health -> PlayerStatus.health
   if(playerHealth != null && health >= 1)
  {
     playerHealth.TakeDamage(damage);
  }
```

}

And i think u use inheritance(class). it better.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to call the `TakeDamage` method on an `int` variable `health`
but i think you are missing a reference to an object of a class that has the `TakeDamage` method which is the commented out part not sure if in purpose .However The `TakeDamage` method is a member of the `PlayerStatus` class, not an `int`. Therefore, you can't call `TakeDamage` directly on an `int` instead
access it through an instance of `PlayerStatus`

```
  private void OnMouseDown()
{
    // Check if playerHealth is not null before calling TakeDamage
    if (playerHealth != null)
    {
        // Call the TakeDamage method from the PlayerStatus script
        playerHealth.TakeDamage(damage);
    }
}
```

Now If the `TakeDamage` method is in the `PlayerStatus` class and you want to decrease the health of the enemy (EnmStatus) when clicked, and then decrease the player's health if the enemy is still alive, you need to make sure the `TakeDamage` method is called on the correct instances. consider the Following structure the whole concept :

**PlayerStatus class** has the `TakeDamage` method to decrease player health.
**EnmStatus class** has the `TakeDamage` method to decrease enemy health.

if the above structure is what you need then Please follow along PlayerStatus script should be something like

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerStatus : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int health;
    public int maxHealth = 10;

    void Start()
    {
        health = maxHealth;
    }

    public void TakeDamage(int amount)
    {
        health -= amount;
        if (health <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

and EnmStatus should be something like

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnmStatus : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlayerStatus playerHealth;
    public int enemyHealth = 5; // Example starting enemy health

    void Start()
    {
        playerHealth = FindObjectOfType<PlayerStatus>();
        if (playerHealth == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("PlayerStatus script not found in the scene.");
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        TakeDamage(2); // Decrease enemy health when clicked

        // If enemy is still alive, decrease player health
        if (enemyHealth >= 1)
        {
            playerHealth.TakeDamage(1); // Adjust the damage as needed
        }
    }

    void TakeDamage(int amount)
    {
        enemyHealth -= amount;
        if (enemyHealth <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

with that order it should work fine , however please make sure both script are attached to the relevant GameObjects